# cx_Freeze cannot find QtDesigner framework

Tags: python, pyqt4, cx-freeze, errno

I am trying to convert my Python app to executable, I found that cx_Freeze would be easiest to modify and use it for my needs.

This is my `setup.py` script:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

includefiles = ['Leaderboard.txt']
includes = ['PyQt4.QtGui', 'PyQt4.QtCore', 'functools.partial', 'multiprocessing.Process', 'sys']


setup(
    name = 'App',
    version = '1.0',
    description = 'Description',
    author = 'ShellRox',
    options = {'build_exe': {'include_files':includefiles}}, 
    executables = [Executable('Project.py', copyDependentFiles=True)]
)
```

Full code [here](http://hastebin.com/nagefutofi.rb).

---

For some reason, i am getting this error:

```
error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'QtDesigner.framework/Versions/4/QtDesigner'
```

Full log [here](http://hastebin.com/ewuyopeneg.vhdl).

However i am not entirely sure what can the problem be, After doing some research i found only one result matching my problem and it wouldn't help at all ( I removed packages though ).

I also added only submodules in `includes` but it still wouldn't help, my guess is it was not looking for modules.

One thing that makes me wonder is if there is something associated with my `reseources.py` file.

I also tried adding QtDesigner location file to Path which didn't update anything else in progress.

## Question:

What can the problem be? How can i blacklist it in cx_Freeze so it wont search for QtDesigner framework (If it is not useful), or do i need to add location in path so it can look for Qt Designer (If so, where would the path be?).

Answer (score 0):

cx_Freeze has an option to exclude binaries. Use that option to block searching for unwanted binaries. 
from the docs

> bin_excludes   -  list of names of files to exclude when determining dependencies of binary files that would normally be included; note that version numbers that normally follow the shared object extension are stripped prior to performing the comparison

Add that option to your setup.py file inside build_exe options like this

```
build_exe_options = {
    "icon": iconPath,
    "packages": packages,
    "includes": includes,
    "include_files": include_files,
    "excludes": excludes,
    "optimize": True,
    "bin_excludes": ["QtDesigner"],
    }
```

But what if your code actually needed that executable file? If you look into the dependency using 'otool' you may find qtdesigner is required by PySide.QtUiTools module.

```
$ otool -L ~/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PySide/QtUiTools.so 
/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PySide/QtUiTools.so:
    @rpath/libpyside-python2.7.1.2.dylib (compatibility version 1.2.0, current version 1.2.2)
    /usr/local/lib/QtDesigner.framework/Versions/4/QtDesigner (compatibility version 4.8.0, current version 4.8.6)
    /usr/local/lib/QtCore.framework/Versions/4/QtCore (compatibility version 4.8.0, current version 4.8.6)
    /usr/local/lib/QtGui.framework/Versions/4/QtGui (compatibility version 4.8.0, current version 4.8.6)
    @rpath/libshiboken-python2.7.1.2.dylib (compatibility version 1.2.0, current version 1.2.2)
    /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 120.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1197.1.1)
```

So you better find where QtDesigner is located and use '*install_name_tool*' to change the search path to the correct location for QtUiTools.so module.